# Saving a string to a txt file on an FTP server

Tags: c#, json, ftp

I am trying to save a string containing Json syntax to a .txt file on an FTP server. 
I tried using this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx which worked great.

But this example takes an existing .txt local file and uploads it to the ftp server.

I would like to directly create / update a txt file on the ftp server from a string variable. Without having first to create the txt file locally in my pc.

Comment: Unless you have direct access to the file system of the FTP server, the only way to do this is to upload a new file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example link is exactly what you need, but you need to get your information from a `MemoryStream` instead of an existing file.

You can turn a string directly into a `Stream` with this:

```
MemoryStream memStr = MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes("asdf"));
```

However, you can shortcut this more by directly turning your string into a `byte array`, avoiding the need to make a `Stream` altogether:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(yourString);

//and now plug that into your example
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```